# Create more serious looking jQuery error dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a jQuery UI class you can use to create a more severe looking error dialog box than the one below?

[image]

This is the HTML we use to create the dialog:

```
<div style="display:none" id="div-dialog-warning">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span><div/></p>
</div>
```

And this is how we show it:

```
$("#div-dialog-warning").dialog({
    title: t,
    resizable: false,
    height: 160,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok" : function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't you just use your own class on the content `<div>`, one that forces a background image of a vicious dog or hostile space alien?

Comment: you should think about excessively using the `<blink>` tag and css properties like `background: evil; font-size:incredibly big`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add the `ui-state-error` class that comes in your theme, like this:

```
$("#div-dialog-warning").dialog({
    title: t,
    resizable: false,
    height: 160,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok" : function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
}).parent().addClass("ui-state-error");
```

Since the dialog gets wrapped we're using [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the container including the titlebar.  Your theme looks like [flick](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Helvetica%2C+Arial%2C+sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=2px&bgColorHeader=dddddd&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=50&borderColorHeader=dddddd&fcHeader=444444&iconColorHeader=0073ea&bgColorContent=ffffff&bgTextureContent=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityContent=75&borderColorContent=dddddd&fcContent=444444&iconColorContent=ff0084&bgColorDefault=f6f6f6&bgTextureDefault=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=100&borderColorDefault=dddddd&fcDefault=0073ea&iconColorDefault=666666&bgColorHover=0073ea&bgTextureHover=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHover=25&borderColorHover=0073ea&fcHover=ffffff&iconColorHover=ffffff&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityActive=65&borderColorActive=dddddd&fcActive=ff0084&iconColorActive=454545&bgColorHighlight=ffffff&bgTextureHighlight=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=cccccc&fcHighlight=444444&iconColorHighlight=0073ea&bgColorError=ffffff&bgTextureError=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityError=55&borderColorError=ff0084&fcError=222222&iconColorError=ff0084&bgColorOverlay=eeeeee&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=80&bgColorShadow=aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=60&thicknessShadow=4px&offsetTopShadow=-4px&offsetLeftShadow=-4px&cornerRadiusShadow=0px) so [here's a demo showing that theme in action](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gvqgP/).

Comment: Note that if your modal is not auto open, this won't work. You'll have to do something like this: `warndialog = $('#div-dialog-warning").dialog({ // all your options here}); warndialog.dialog("open").parent().addClass("ui-state-error");` The class can only be added after initialization, at least for my version of jQuery.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is old but, actually, it would be more suitable to use the built-in "dialogClass" option, like so:

```js
$("#div-dialog-warning").dialog( {
    buttons: {
        "Ok" : function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    dialogClass: "error",
    height: 160,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: t
} );
```

Comment: Did you mean to suggest dialogClass: "ui-state-error" ?  That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

use this excellent and simple jquery notification and alert plugin

[ned.im/noty](http://ned.im/noty)

in the demo folder there is a modal sample

> NOTY is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to create alert - success -
>   error - warning - information - confirmation messages as an
>   alternative the standard alert dialog. Each notification is added to a
>   queue.

Answer (score 1):

`dialogClass` is deprecated in v1.12 of jQuery (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass)

Use `classes` instead (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-classes)

So for >= v1.12 would be:

```
$("#div-dialog-warning").dialog({
    title: t,
    resizable: false,
    height: 160,
    modal: true,
    classes: {
        "ui-dialog": "ui-state-error"
    },
    buttons: {
        "Ok" : function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Take a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#theming for all theme able parts

and http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/ for all css classes.

(Don't include the . (dot) in the value string)